# Ruby: Undefined method `bucket' for #<Aws::S3::Client>

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the `aws-sdk-s3` gem, I am currently able to upload items to buckets and create signed URLs, and am trying to determine if an object exists in a bucket or not. All the documentation I see says client.bucket('bucketname') should work, but in my case it is not. I've tried:

```
client.bucket('bucketname')
client.bucket['bucketname']
client.buckets('bucketname')
client.buckets['bucketname']
```

but none work. This suggestion using `head_object` is a possibility (https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues/160), but I'm still curious why `bucket` isn't working.

DOCS:
https://gist.github.com/hartfordfive/19097441d3803d9aa75ffe5ecf0696da
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/index.html#Resource_Interfaces

Comment: Do you get an undefined method error when calling client.bucket? It could be that client is not defined properly. If you are using pry, you can try `ls client` to see what methods are available on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `bucket` or `buckets` on [`Aws::S3::Resource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Resource.html) instance and not on [`Aws::S3::Client`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html) instance as an error states.

And the links you provided as well as [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/index.html#Resource_Interfaces) show that:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::InstanceProfileCredentials.new()
)
bucket =  s3.bucket('my-daily-backups')
```

Comment: Doh. Long night, should have came back to this. I could've sworn an example or two I came across used the `Client` directly. I still couldn't find any examples using `InstanceProfileCredentials` with credentials, and the obvious id/key parameters didn't take. Had to use `Resource.new(client: <client>)`. Thanks.